# Is a multivendor setup possible with Moltin?

Tags: moltin

On Moltin's website at https://www.moltin.com/cross-platform-ecommerce/ it advertises as part of their features,

> Marketpalce - Allow multiple sellers to come together in one place and market their goods or services.

However, I can't seem to find any other references online or in the API for a multivendor setup. Does Moltin support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and we do have multiple users doing so, it does require some additional logic/work to implement - depending on how advanced it is.

We're working hard on making it easier, and we'll add resources soon. If you can contact us via the Slack Hub (https://www.moltin.com/resources/), I'd be happy to help you get set up :)